# The relative homology of a pair $H_n(S_n, A)$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

At page 136 of Hatcher's [book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) he says:

> By excision, the central term $H_n(S^n, S^n - f^{-1}(y))$ in the preceding diagram is the direct sum of the groups $H_n(U_i, U_i-x_i) \approx \mathbb{Z}$.

Here $n>0$, $f:S^n \longrightarrow S^n$ is a continuous function which $y \in S^n$ has finite pre-image $x_1,...,x_m$ and $U_i$ are disjoint open subsets of $S_n$ containing $x_i$.

I understand why it happens, and then we have $H_n(S^n, S^n - f^{-1}(y)) \approx \mathbb{Z}\oplus \ldots\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ (m-times). But we know that $H_n(S_n) \approx \mathbb{Z}$ and we see $H_n(S^n - f^{-1}(y))$ as a subgroup of $H_n(S_n)$ to define the quotient $H_n(S^n, S^n - f^{-1}(y)) \dot{=} \frac{H_n(S^n)}{H_n(S^n - f^{-1}(y))}$. So the isomorphism $\xi : H_n(S^n) \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ sends $H_n(S^n - f^{-1}(y))$ onto a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ and passing to quotient, we have
$$H_n(S^n, S^n - f^{-1}(y)) \approx \frac{\mathbb Z}{\xi(H_n(S^n - f^{-1}(y)))}.$$ 
Since all subgroups of $\mathbb Z$ are $n\mathbb Z$ for some $n \in \mathbb Z$, we have $H_n(S^n - f^{-1}(y))\approx \mathbb Z_n$, which gives a contradiction.

I can't find the mistake in this argument (that can be done for all $A\subset S^n$, and then all groups $H_n(S^n,A)$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_n$ for some $n$), but I believe that it is just a detail that I didn't see.

> Can anyone see the mistake?

Comment: In general $H_n(X,A)$ is not the same as $H_n(X)/H_n(A)$.

Comment: Anyway, $H_n(S^n-f^{-1}(y))$ is $0$ since $S^n-F$, where $F\ne\emptyset$ is a finite set, is homotopy equivalent to a wedge sum of $|F|-1$ spheres of dimension $n-1$.